# Elasticsearch master slave cofiguration

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-map-reduce

How to configure elasticsearch in master node and data node?What is the difference between both type of elasticsearch cluster ?How we get beneficial in elasticsearch with hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

All nodes are eligible become master or data nodes by default. One node can be a master node and a data node in the same time. However, there many advantages to split master role and data role from a node. In a big Elasticsearch cluster, since the stable master nodes are important for the healthy cluster, people would like to keep master nodes away from indexing and searching pressure, assign dedicated servers as master nodes.

Master nodes are responsible for creating or deleting an index, tracking which nodes are part of the cluster, and deciding which shards to allocate to which nodes. You can configure a node as a master eligible node by setting:

```
node.master: true 
node.data: false 
node.ingest: false
```

Data nodes are in response for holding data, indexing and searching. These operations are  I/O-, memory-, and CPU-intensive. You can configure a node as a data eligible node by setting:

```
node.master: false 
node.data: true 
node.ingest: false
```

Further, there is a dedicated coordinating node, which only routes requests to data nodes and doesn’t have to handle master’s duties, just works like a load balancer. You can configure a node as a coordinating node by settings:

```
node.master: false 
node.data: false 
node.ingest: false 
search.remote.connect: false
```

The distributed nature of Elasticsearch are suitable for Hadoop parallel computing. Hadoop can leverage the shards provided by Elasticsearch to get the required data efficiently.

Elasticsearch node types and configuration for further reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-node.html